# Git detached head pushing local changes to branch in repo

Tags: git

My output is following:

```
(DRF_env) D:\Development\SHK\OnlyDRF\server>git branch -a
* (HEAD detached at origin/test_branch)
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/test_branch
```

I did `git fetch --all` and basically I have made some changes locally which I want to push to `test_branch` which exists in my repo.

What should I do to resolve this issue with detached head? so that I can push all changes from my local to test_branch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on that output, you're pointed at the remote's `test_branch` but you don't actually have a corresponding local branch.  I assume, then, that your changes are in the work tree.  So:

```
git checkout -b test_branch
git branch -u origin/test_branch
```

The first will create the local branch and get you out of detached head state.  The second should set up tracking between the local and remote branches.  Then add and commit your changes and push as usual.

**UPDATE** - Comments raised the question: is a local branch necessary?

A local branch isn't necessary (hence `git push origin HEAD:test_branch` *can* work), but it is useful and it is the normal way to work with git.  If you don't have local branches, and also don't always push changes to the remote for one branch before moving to work on another, things will get very difficult for you and changes may end up getting lost (or at least difficult to locate).

The good news is, it's actually quite easy to get the local branches.  At some point you must have said

```
git checkout origin/test_branch
```

If you had instead said

```
git checkout test_branch
```

then git would have noticed that there's no such local branch, but there's a remote branch of the same name.  So it would create the local branch and set up tracking between the two automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it solved my issue! Is it always necessary to create a new local branch for each branch on repo that we want to use?

Comment: Strictly speaking, no, but it will make your life easier to have a local branch.  I'll update to provide some information about this...

Comment: Just to add a little bit of knowledge: Branches are extremely useful. I don't want to imply that you should avoid them. However there are use cases when they are an overkill. For example, say you are asked to work on a little something on a given branch that is on a remote but that you don't want to have locally (a feature branch that someone else is working on, you are asked to work on a very simple thing there, you don't want to pollute your repo with a local branch). So ```git checkout the-remote/a-branch; fix fix; git add .; git commit "blah"; git push the-remote HEAD:a-branch;```.

Comment: @Edmundo - Yes, that would be a case where you *will* push the changes before moving on to another branch, so it can work without trouble.  But I still don't do it, because I find it just as easy to add `git branch -d a-branch` when I'm done as it would be to remember a syntax that I rarely use for `push`.  Ultimately that comes down to personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

just push into the remote specifying that you want to push HEAD into the branch:

```
git push origin HEAD:test_branch
```

That is assuming you don't want to create a local branch for it.

Comment: Since the branch list says "detached *at* origin/test_branch" (rather than "detached *from*...") it'll probably just say "already up to date" with that.  Add/commit first then do this, and yes it should work without the local branch; in my answer I just happened to assume the opposite - i.e. that a local branch would be wanted.